# ERROR in node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(37,24): error TS1005: ';' expected

Tags: node.js, angular, lodash

I have an Angular-5 application with:

```
"@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.4",
```

Initially, When I did ng serve, I got this error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":["C://xampp//htdocs//angular-laravel-hrms//HRMS2UI//src//styles"]}!./src/styles.scss Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (83)

But when I did:

> npm rebuild node-sass

the error changed to:

> ERROR in node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(37,24): error TS1005: ';' expected.
> node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(483,22): error TS1005: ';' expected.
> node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(483,41): error TS1005: ',' expected.
> node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(483,44): error TS1005: '(' expected.

I did npm i --package-lock-only

but the error is still there.

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the version of node is wrong, you must downgrade node, or upgrade node-sass, until you have a compatible pair. If the node version is supported, you may just need to run:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: the error changed to:   ERROR in src/app/core/scrollbar/scrollbar-options.ts(3,14): error TS2322: Type '{ damping: number; thumbMinSize: number; renderByPixels: true; alwaysShowTracks: false; continuou...' is not assignable to type 'ScrollbarOptions'.    What do I do?
  Property 'delegateTo' is missing in type '{ damping: number; thumbMinSize: number; renderByPixels: true; alwaysShowTracks: false; continuou...'.

Answer (score 2):

You can install types for an old version of typescript with using npm tags. For example lodash types for typescript 2.5

`npm i -D @types/lodash@ts2.5`

Then you run the following commands

```
npm rebuild node-sass
npm install --scripts-prepend-node-path
npm start
```